# Serializing and Deserializing Raw Json String using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson Fasterxml version 2.8.0 to serialize and deserialize json as follows:

```
public static byte[] serializeData(Object object){
   final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
  String json = "{ \"id\" : \"user1\" }"; // need to escape or else compiler complains

  byte[] result = serializeData(json);

  final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(result);

  System.out.println(json);
  System.out.println(jsonNode.toString());
  System.out.println(jsonNode.getNodeType());

  Iterator<String> fields = jsonNode.fieldNames();
  while(fields.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("field - " + fields.next());
  }
}
```

The output was:

```
{ "id" : "user1" }
"{ \"id\" : \"user1\" }"
STRING
```

Notice there is no output lines for printing the field names. So, it seems like the `JsonNode` does not have any properties and for some reason the `toString()` has escape chars in them. Am I using this library in the wrong manner? Why is that when deserializing the byte array results in a behavior where I can't find the fields I initially added?

**Updates**

Providing some more context of the application. The app receives the Json as a String input. The code that deserializes the Json is not aware of the model of the Json. It just expects it to be valid Json object so that it can iterate through the various fields in it.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking a JSON string to java Object, that is the key issue here.

```
  String json = "{ \"id\" : \"user1\" }"; // need to escape or else compiler complains

  byte[] result = serializeData(json);
```

Your `String json`  is just a String, it does not matter what it's contents are, using `mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object)` just serializes a String thus resulting in a single JSON Node of type STRING.

To serialize an Object that has a field id of type String, you **need** to serialize an object with a field named `id` of type `String`.

For example :

```
public class User {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

This type User can be serialized to `{"id":"User1"}` (if the id field is set to "User1").

In the following example you either start from a POJO (`User user = new User();`) or you start from valid json string (`String json = "{ \"id\" : \"user1\" }";`).

In the first case you first map the object into json bytes, then you **parse** those bytes to get a JSONNode (a kind of DOM tree for json ).

In the second case you just **parse** the bytes to get the node, you don't writeValueAsBytes of the json string, beacause you would just *stringify* twice thus getting just a value node of STRING type.

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setId("user1");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    byte[] jsonBytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(user);


    System.out.println(new String(jsonBytes)); // will print {"id":"user1"}

    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonBytes);
    Iterator<String> names = node.fieldNames();
    while (names.hasNext()) {
        String name = (String) names.next();
        JsonNodeType type = node.get(name).getNodeType();
        System.out.println(name+":"+type); //will print id:STRING
    }

    // This is not a object to serialize 
    // This is a string to parse into a json object
    String json = "{ \"id\" : \"user1\" }";

    JsonNode node2 = mapper.readTree(json.getBytes());
    names = node.fieldNames();
    while (names.hasNext()) {
        String name = (String) names.next();
        JsonNodeType type = node.get(name).getNodeType();
        System.out.println(name+":"+type); //will print id:STRING
    }
```

Comment: I just rewrote the whole thing because comment where getting out of control and cluttering the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calling `toString()` inside `writeValueAsBytes` method which converts object into string. Following should work fine:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
node.put("id", "user1");
byte[] result = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(node);
final JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(result);
System.out.println(json);
Iterator<String> fieldNames = json.fieldNames();
while(fieldNames.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(fieldNames.next());
}
if(json.has("id")){
  System.out.println("No id");
}
```

**Update**

If you do not know the type of the object you want your json to be deserialized into, then you can just deserialize it into a `Map`, e.g.:

```
Map<String, Object> result = mapper.readValue(result, new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() {});
```

Comment: In my application, I actually have the possibility of receiving the json as a String input. How would I handle that scenario?

So, I can't do something like `mapper.writeValueAsBytes(node);`

Comment: Could you post the sample json? If it does not have escaped double quotes (i.e. if it's a valid `json` and not `json` converted into `string`) then you can easily deserialize it using `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: Sorry, can't see the updates related to my question. Anyway, it looks like you don't know the type of object while deserializing. In that case, best bet would be to use `Map`, I have updated the answer with an example.